# Buffer overflow - The changes of variables

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

```
void go()
{
    //{1}
    char buffer[2];
    gets(buffer);
    //{2}
    cout << allow;
}
```

I tried to run the procedure above in 2 cases:

-1st: I declare "int allow;' at position 1

-2nd: I declare "int allow;' at position 2

In both cases, when i tried to enter the string "123" (without the quotation marks), the allow's value was 51. 
However, as I read about the memory layout, only in the first case, the position of "allow" in the stack is before buffer, which means that when the string is longer than the buffer, the value of "allow" is changed.

Then, I tried to declare "char sth[10]" in both position. This time, only when I declared sth in first position, the value of it was changed.

Can anyone explain what happened?

Comment: Did you set allow to any other value before `gets...`?

Comment: There is no guarantee how the variables are laid out in memory based on where they are declared.

Comment: Wow, you are actually trying to detect stack smashing at application level? In any case, I second Paul Tomblin's comment above.

Comment: @Amit: yes, i have set it to zero.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: I'm taking a course in Coursera, and the Professor comments that the arguments of procedure are pushed into the stack in the reverse order and the variables are pushed in the order they are declared.
Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Than as Paul said, no guarantees, but it looks like your compiler is trying really hard to help you :-)

Comment: And as for your latest comment, non of these are "*arguments of a procedure*". These are all local variables.

Comment: @user3425082  Arguments could be placed in registers and have nothing to do with the stack.  I really don't know why a professor would waste your time with this, except possibly to tell you that overflowing a buffer **may** affect other variables.

Answer (score 3):

Since changing `allow` via overflow is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the compiler might even not have a variable `allow` at all and change your code to `cout << 0` instead when compiling with optimization. This is **not** a valid way to check for overflow, regardless of where you put `allow`.

To emphasize: All changes of `allow` you observe are the result of UB. There are no guarantees on this in the standard what so ever. You can go ahead and speculate on why you see this output today, on you system, with this very toolchain, but the outcome might change to *anything* (like your program moving your lawn or stealing the crown jewels) for *any* reason.

Indeed, there is no way to use `gets` safely. This is why it is removed in both the current C++ and C standard.

You can use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead:

```
string buffer;
std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
```